Sending data from react app to google sheets w axios
I'm super new with React and Typescript, just started this week. I'm trying to make a form and upon form submission the data is sent to Google Sheets. I came across a few articles, and went with the tutorial with using axios to post and turning my google sheets to a restapi using sheet.best, however, i soon realized it's not optimal. Is there anyway I can still use axios to post data to my google sheets without using sheet.best? What would be the best alternatives? I've looked at Google Sheets API and tried to add it to my code but it hasnt worked. This is the code. Again I'm really new and I'm not sure if I'm doing things right T-T
"use client";
import axios from 'axios';
import './waitlist.css';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'antd';




  const JoinWaitList = () => {
    const[fname, setFName] = useState("");
    const[lname, setLName] = useState("");
    const[email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const[phone, setPhone] = useState("");
    const[sms, setSMS] = useState(false);
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);



   const handleFNameChange = event => {
    setFName(event.target.value)
  };
   const handleLNameChange = event => {
    setLName(event.target.value)
  };
   const handleEmailChange = event => {
    setEmail(event.target.value)
  };
   const handlePhoneChange = event => {
    setPhone(event.target.value)
  };
   const handleSMSChange = event => {
      setSMS(event.target.checked)
  };



      const showModal = () => {
         setIsModalOpen(true);
      };

      const handleOk = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
      };


     const handleSubmit = event => {
      //const formEle = (document.querySelector('form-container')!);
      event.preventDefault();
  

  const objt = {fname, lname, email, phone, sms };

  console.log(
    `\n
    First Name: ${fname} \n
    Last Name: ${lname} \n
    Email Address: ${email} \n
    Phone Number: ${phone} \n
    SMS Promotions: ${sms}
    `)
    /*
here is me trying to use googlesheets as rest api
    const formData = new FormData(formEle)
         fetch("google-script-url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      mode: "no-cors"
    });
    */
    
    axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/762ac4d1-2113-4f9f-bfa7-881a21b0db4e', 
      objt
    )
    
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      
      setFName('');
      setLName('');
      setEmail('');
      setPhone('');
      setSMS(false);
      showModal();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };


The documentation of the Google Rest API for google sheet is there: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest . They provide a JS client: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/ Good luck

If Google Sheet API is too much of a hassle for you, try Zerosheets because it would be an easier time for you using Axios around it. I use it at my own projects.
